# UITableViewCell still shows image overlapping the text after clearing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that displays a bunch of 'n' rows (all using the standard `UITableViewCell` class), the last of which has an image (a little '+' icon to indicate 'Add record').

Suppose the following scenario:

1. The user clicks on that last row, which pushes a new view controller onto the navigation stack
2. The user then fills out a form to add a new record, which is saved using Core Data
3. The form is then popped from the navigation stack, returning you to that first `UITableViewController`, and I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to make sure the new state is displayed

You now see 'n+1' rows, the last of which now shows the '+' image. The problem is that I'm experiencing a bug where row 'n' still shows the '+' image, except that it overlaps with the text label for that cell (I could understand the bug where it showed the '+' image to the left of the text - I explicity set `imageView.image = nil` to avoid this - but the fact that the image overlaps with the text makes this one really weird).

Here's the code for my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCellStyle cellStyle;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];        
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if ((self.selectedCategory != nil) && (indexPath.row < [self.selectedCategory.subjects count])) {
        Subject *managedObject = (Subject*)[self.selectedCatSubjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = managedObject.name;
        cell.imageView.image = nil; // Needed in case there used to be a "+" icon
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add subject...";
        [cell.imageView initWithImage:_addIcon]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with reuse of the cell. Can you try using a different cell identifier for the last cell alone.

Comment: replace NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; with NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I think that slightly defeats the point of reusing cells in the first place, doesn't it? @7KV7's method sounds like less overkill

Comment: @andygeers ofcourse it it not the correct way..That is why I put it as a comment..I just want to know you still has the same problem after using different cell Identifier..Frankly I dont think it is your problem..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Oh, I see, sorry... Well, it turns out that the problem persists even without the cell reuse

Comment: I had a similar feature in one of my apps where i had a load more button as the last cell. I used different identifiers for last cell and it worked for me. `if(indexPath.row==[self.selectedCategory.subjects count]) {cellIdentifier = @"PlusCell";}`

Comment: @7KV7 Ah!! I've got it! I was trying the approach by @Krishnabhadra of using the section&row index as the identifier, but that doesn't help because the row index stays the same even as the cell's use changes. If I explicit change it to something like "PlusCell" for the last row, then it fixes the bug. Could you post that as a proper answer so I can vote it up and accept it?

Comment: @andygeers: I have added it as an answer. Thanks mate:)

Comment: @andygeers: I have added it as an answer as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar feature in one of my apps where i had a load more button as the last cell. I used different identifiers for last cell and it worked for me.

```
if(indexPath.row==[self.selectedCategory.subjects count]) 
{
cellIdentifier = @"PlusCell";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me.**

replace :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

with :

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient unless you have a very good reason for doing so - you lose all the benefits of reusing cells. The accepted answer does the job - because it's only the final cell that is different, and so only the final cell that needs a different identifier

Comment: @andygeers i dont think it's inefficient because better to set Unique identifier with each cell instead of checking cell with if else condition. how ever there is multiple different type of cell.